# How does Cake PHP model associations work between different Data Sources

Tags: cakephp, model, datasource, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have been playing around with cakephp for the last few days, and I am trying to work out how the associations work between different data sources. I have been searching on google, but haven't had much success.

For instance, lets say I have two models, one that stores its data in a MySQL database, and another that stores data in an XML file. They both have HABTM set linking to each other. So, when one is searched for, how does the system join both data sources, and how efficient is it (i.e. avoiding the N+1 problem)?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into similar problem using cake 3.

I am using Postgres and my data resides in different schemas which I define as different datasources. To make relations work I had to make addition to table definition for cake to issue separate query to join data.

Here is relationship definition from my AccountsTable which is stored in comp_x.accounts and belongs to Banks which is stored in public.banks

```
$this->belongsTo('Banks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'bank_id',
        'strategy' => 'select' // this is the change I made
]);
```

This way cake makes separate query to fetch bank data and not to try join to non existing table comp_x.banks in same query.

In your question you mentioned HABTM relationships. I believe it could be similar. I have nothing to add about efficiency as I have not tested it yet on large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. When you create a `relation` all cake does is build up the language that MySQL requires for fetching data.

Cake has nothing to do with how that relation equates to the actual data that MySQL normally fetches.

Comment: So, does that mean that the MySQL database is searched through, then the resulting data is used to pull data from the XML data file?

Comment: There is nothing in cakephp to use xml as a datasource. There is nothing in cake to link xml and mysql.

Comment: How about with other datasource types, other than XML? So MySQL and Postgres/MSSQL/LDAP/JSON, or is it the same story?

Comment: I think you need to re-read the answer. The answer is still no.